# Execute command within variable

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to execute a command, stored within a variable:

```
cmd="grep -i \"word1\" filename | grep -i \"word2\""
eval $cmd
```

But when I execute the script I get the errors:

```
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: grep: No such file or directory
```

How can I execute commands like the one in my example without getting this errors?

Comment: missing closing double quote.

Comment: I cannot confirm that. This works for me, even with whitespace: `cmd="grep \"foo bar\" file | grep \"match\""; eval $cmd`. In general you should use `eval "$cmd"` but I have no idea how that can cause this error. Please run `set -x` before executing the commands and add the output to your question.

Comment: what shell are you using? type `echo $0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote `"$cmd"` - and maybe avoid the `"`double-quotes. Anyway, to run this you do need to `eval` it - and this is due to the `|pipe`. A shell variable does not expand beyond the limits of a single simple command - and you're trying to run a compound command.

So:

```
cmd='grep -i "word1" filename | grep -i "word2"'

eval "$cmd"
```

Probably when you were expanding `$cmd` without quotes you ran into filename generation and/or `$IFS` issues. Just make sure it's reliably quoted and you'll be fine. Also verify that whatever is in `"word[12]"` doesn't contain double-quotes or backslashes or whatever - else you'll need to reevaluate your quoting style there.

Looking closer now at your error and I can tell you exactly what it was:

```
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: grep: No such file or directory
```

So if I do:

```
echo | echo
```

The first `echo` prints a `\n`ewline to the second `echo`'s `stdin`. If I do:

```
set \| echo
echo "$@"
```

The first `echo` prints each of its arguments, which are `|`pipe and `echo` respectively.

The difference is that the `|`pipe in the first case is interpreted by the shell's parser to be a token and is interpreted as such. In the second case, at the same the shell is scanning for the `|`pipe token it is also scanning for the `$`expand token - and so the `|`pipe is not yet there to be found because `"$@"` has not yet been replaced with its value.

So if you do:

```
grep -i "word" filename \| grep -i "word2"
```

...you're likely to get the same results because the `|` there does not delimit the commands, and is instead an argument to `grep` in its *infiles* position.

Here's a look at how many fields you get when you split `$cmd` with a default `$IFS`:

```
printf '<%s> ' $cmd
<grep> <-i> <"word1"> <filename> <|> <grep> <-i> <"word2">
```

And here's what filename generation might do:

```
touch 'echo 1simple &&' 'echo 2simple'
eval echo*
```

Comment: There was always an `eval` in the question thus I don't understand your second sentence. What effect do you think the `"$cmd"` quotes have on the pipe? There could indeed be problems with pathname expansion but they would not affect the limits of a single simple command because they are determined before. I guess your last remark is the point: "Dangerous" characters in `word1` or `filename`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - the `eval` stuff was mostly about a lot of the other answers here that suggest it not be used. An `alias` could work, too, but I was just talking about the mode the asker says he uses. The `"$cmd"` quotes serve to better protect the parameters, and there is the way that `eval` will concat on spaces if it's handed multiple args. And various characters - newlines, whatever - will split out the command in all kinds of ways if the it is evaluated at the wrong time. It is best to leave it a single field. And yes - pathname expansion will affect simple command limits.

Comment: "pathname expansion will affect simple command limits" – Would you mind giving an example for that?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - `touch 'echo 1simple command &&' 'echo 2simple commands'; v=echo*; eval $v`; The whole point of `eval` is that it gives the shell's *parser* another pass at the arguments - that is what is meant by *twice-evaluated*.

Answer (score 0):

As for me it wrong way to use *variable* to save and to execute any command. There is better choice -- *function*:

```
my_cmd() {grep -i "word1" filename | grep -i "word2"}
```

That is all.

Or you can use different arguments like:

```
my_cmd() {grep -i "$1" "$3" | grep -i "$2"}
```

Then call it by

```
my_cmd word1 word2 filename
```

Comment: The given code was just an example, the command is not always the same and is generated.

Comment: It is not a problem. You can call *function* with arguments: `my_cmd(){grep -i "$1" "$3" | grep -i "$2"}` Then call it `my_cmd word1 word2 filename`

Comment: @Luxo see edited answer

Comment: With generating the command I ment that it's possible that you end up getting a command like grep -i "word1" filename | grep -i "word2" | grep -i "word3" | grep -vi "excludeword"

Comment: @Luxo There are many ways to avoid `eval` use. One of it can be a *loop*: `my_cmd() { result=$(grep -i "$1" "${!#}") ; for i in $(seq  2 $[$#-1]) ; do result=$(echo "$result" | grep -i "${!i}") ; done ; echo "$result" })`

Answer (score -1):

For the example you posted, you shouldn't need the eval. Just execute the variable like so:

```
cmd="grep -i \"word1\" filename | grep -i \"word2\""; # added missing " at the end    
$cmd
```

Watch your quotes. Maybe something like this is less prone to mistakes:

```
cmd='grep -i "word1" filename | grep -i "word2"';
```

Comment: I'm still having the same errors

Comment: if you could paste something more like your exact code I could probably help more. Im guessing it's likely a quote issue, but hard to tell. I ran that example I posted and it worked for me.